# Is the map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f\left((x,y,z)^\top\right)=\max\{ x,y,z\}$ $\mathbb{R}$-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to see if I am solving right this exercise.

Is the map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$f\left(\,\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\,\right)=\max\{ x,y,z\}$ $\mathbb{R}$-linear ?

For me it is not, since if we take $x>y>z$ and $f\left(-1\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\,\right)=-z\;$ but $\;-1f\left(\,\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\,\right)=-x$

Am I right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, although it could be argued that taking a concrete example (such as $x=2$, $y=1$, and $z=0$) would be better.

You can also use the fact that$$\overbrace{f\bigl((1,0,0)+(-1,0,0)\bigr)}^{\phantom0=0}\ne\overbrace{f(1,0,0)}^{\phantom1=1}+\overbrace{f(-1,0,0)}^{\phantom0=0}.$$